# "The EM algorithm failed to converge in 25 iterations"

Tags: spss, missing-data, expectation-maximization

When I Replace Missing Values - Expectation-Maximization in SPSS, I receive the following message: The EM algorithm failed to converge in 25 iterations.  Should the algorithm be able to converge?

Can anybody help me? :)

I have 20 variables and 299 cases (217 cases listwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, increase the number of iterations (on the EM subdialog box).  Try, say, 100

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out to be that I included the Case IDs with the quantitative variables that I was testing.

The problem was fixed when I removed the Case IDs from the list that is being tested.

Good luck.